# Wordpress - Use featured image as div background within shortcode in PHP

Tags: php, css, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to get the featured image of a post in wordpress and output it as the background image of a div and align it to the bottom right of the div.

So far I have the code shown below but the `background-image: url(' . wp_get_attachment_url() . ');` is returning as `background-image: url();` when the code is executed.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

```
<?php
    query_posts(array( 'category_name' => 'what-we-do'));
    if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
<div>
    <?php 
        echo do_shortcode( '
            [expand title="' . get_the_title() . '" swaptitle="Close" trigpos="below" id="' . get_the_ID() . '" trigclass="arrowright" rel="whatwedo-highlander"]
                <h4 class="collapse-inner-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h4>
                <div class="whatwedo-collapse-background-img" style="background-image: url(' . wp_get_attachment_url() . '); background-position: right bottom;">
                    <div class="whatwedo-collapse-content">' . get_the_content() . '</div>
                </div>
            [/expand]
        ' ); 
    ?>
</div>

<?php
    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );`

then us `$image[0]` When setting the `background-image`

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman. Thank you for your quick response and clear instructions. Worked perfectly.